# Scala: Why is it necessary to assign values to a var/val during declaration

Tags: scala, declaration

Unless I've been doing it wrong. It doesn't seem like we can do things like:

```
var x;
x = 1;
```

in Scala, but rather you have to declare and assign a value to it. Are there any reasons for why this is the case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The obvious reason is to help not leave variables uninitialized.
Note that in your declaration without initialization, you will also need to specify the type.

```
var x: Type;
```

gives the following error:

> only classes can have declared but undefined members (Note that variables need to be initialized to be defined)

Actually only abstract classes can declare members without defining them. You can still get the desired behavior (variables initialized to a default value) as

```
var x: Type = _
```

If `Type` is a reference type, `x` will be `null`. This scenario is useful, for example, in case where a factory method completes initialization of an object after object construction.

Comment: Nice explanation of the `var` case.  Since you can't reassign `val` identifiers after declaration, lifting this restriction would effectively encourage proliferation of multiple names for `null`.  Which would be bad.

Comment: I copy and paste your example with `var x: Long = _` but it gives me error: `Local variables must be initialized`. Is there more newcomers to Scala need to know in order to use your solution? For instance, as the OP is requesting a numeric type, what would be a suitable numeric `Type` to use for `x`?

Comment: As you can see, that the `var ... = _` notation would work only for class members and not for local variables. I believe there aren't any situations warranting uninitialized local variables.

Comment: So what should be done if I have `if (condition) {x = expensive1()} else {x = expensive2()}` ?

Comment: @LumiG you can do `val x = if (condition) expensive1() else expensive2()`.